# Read a JSON file into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read a series of JSON files and convert to Pandas DataFrame, however, none of the examples I've followed worked for the reading part.

This is an example of JSON files I have:

```
{
    "created_at": "Thu Nov 02 01:09:12 +0000 2017",
    "text": "RT @coindesk: SEC: Celebrity ICO Endorsements Could Be Illegal gHoWduXOBp t.co/iyWla0Ryuk",
    "tweet_id": 925892516087558145,
    "user_id": 153962533,
    "user_name": "Christine Duhaime"
}{
    "created_at": "Thu Nov 02 01:09:44 +0000 2017",
    "text": "Cornell Professor C t.co/RuNu6UQyr9",
    "tweet_id": 925892650884108289,
    "user_id": 1255045351,
    "user_name": "Local SEO Somerset"
}
```

I've tried:

```
with codecs.open('./output/streamer_20171022-2010.json', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

That resulted in

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 416 (char 415)
```

I also tried reading line by line...no success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file has an invalid format. You can only have one top level element in valid JSON

Try Placing the top level objects into an array.

```
[
    { "created_at": "Thu Nov 02 01:09:12 +0000 2017", 
      "text": "RT @coindesk: SEC: Celebrity ICO Endorsements Could Be Illegal gHoWduXOBp t.co/iyWla0Ryuk",
      "tweet_id": 925892516087558145,
      "user_id": 153962533, 
      "user_name": "Christine Duhaime" 
    }, { 
      "created_at": "Thu Nov 02 01:09:44 +0000 2017",
      "text": "Cornell Professor C t.co/RuNu6UQyr9", 
      "tweet_id": 925892650884108289,
      "user_id": 1255045351,
      "user_name": "Local SEO Somerset" 
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi Caio, I had a difference here. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Cheers :)
Happy coding